# Best practice for machine up monitor using prometheus?

Tags: prometheus

What approach are folks using to see if a machine is up/down as opposed to the node_exporter up/down (which could be down for other reasons) ?

- ping?
- ssh port check?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [blackbox_exporter](https://github.com/prometheus/blackbox_exporter) to probe for connectivity of port 80/443 (http/https) or port 22 (ssh) depending on what runs on your host and then alert on `probe_success == 0`.

Comment: That's what I was thinking. Will give it go.